# Can an existing device-name be given to a new EBS volume being attached to an Amazon EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

Let's say there is a single disk `Disk 0` at an Amazon EC2 instance `Instance1` with the corresponding EBS volume having the device-name `/dev/sd1`. Let's say this disk maps to C-drive on the VM.

Now can we create a new EBS volume attach it to `Instance1` with the same device-name `/dev/sd1`?

If this is possible, does it mean, after the volume is attached, we can go ahead and extend the existing C-drive at `Instance1`, without having to go through the process of detaching it first, creating a snapshot etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an EBS volume is already mounted at `/dev/sd1`, it is not possible to mount another volume as that device.

First, detach the existing volume, then attach a new volume.

To extend the size of an EBS volume:

- **Detach** the EBS volume from the EC2 instance
- **Create Snapshot** of the EBS volume
- **Create Volume** from the snapshot, making the volume larger
- **Attach** the new EBS volume to the EC2 instance

The disk partition will also need to be extended. This can be done with the **Disk Management** console (Windows) or with the `resize2fs` command (Linux).